# Jquery toggle elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element

I have this HTML

```
<div id="text-slide"><ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="" id="toggle1">Webdesign</a>
</li><div class="toggle1" style="display:none;width:45%; position:absolute;left: 16%; top:0;"><h2>Webdesign</h2><p>Test</p></div>
 <li>
 <a href="" id="toggle2">Design de identidades</a>
</li><div class="toggle2" style="display:none;width:45%;position:absolute;left: 16%; top:0;"><h2>Design de identidades</h2><p>Test</p></div></ul></div>
```

And I created this jquery for two elements separated

```
 $(function() {
        $('#toggle1').click(function() {
        $(".toggle1").toggle("slow");
        $(".toggle2").hide("slow");
        $(this).addClass('current');

        $("#toggle2").removeClass('current');

        return false;
     });
      $('#toggle2').click(function() {
        $(".toggle2").toggle("slow");
        $(".toggle1").hide("slow");
        $(this).addClass('current');

        $("#toggle1").removeClass('current');

        return false;
     });                               
});
```

Someone knows how to add many elements and simplify the jquery script?
I tried to add the third element  with the same jquery but dont works for me.

Comment: You should post what you tried and what about it isn't working.

Comment: How come li and div elements are siblings?? this makes the html invalid

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xambha25/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

HTML

```
<div class="toggle">toggle</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="toggle">toggle</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="toggle">toggle</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
<div class="toggle">toggle</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {display:none;}
```

JS

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    if($(this).next('.content').is(':hidden')) {
        $('.content').slideUp();
        $(this).next('.content').slideDown();
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmkdm6ko/6/)

Comment: Style your elements as you wish, this just toggles the visibility.

Comment: Can be make it like this with css?http://img.pixady.com/2015/07/887822_exemple.jpg

Comment: That`s it , i have one more question . And how i can add for the current element some style in css?? For example , like a:current/a:active

Comment: Hi Skatch, i created an index with the elements from ur fiddle but when i pressed on the toggle element , nothing happened.

Comment: It works in the fiddle, so you are doing something wrong. I can't debug that for you. :)

Comment: It`s because fiddle is "onLoad" and my index.html is not . For exemple try it with "no wrap - in <head>. How can I solve that?

Comment: Add the script below the html, or wrap it inside `$(document).ready(function(){/* code here */});`

Comment: Done . Thanks. He doesn't work without "$(document).ready(function(){/* code here */});"

Comment: It will work without it if you put the code after the html. Nevermind, you can do it this way too.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the selector not() for this task it works great for me.

```
$('.content').not($this).slideUp('slow');
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/nmkdm6ko/2/)

Comment: And how i can add for the current element some style in css?? For example , like a:current/a:active.

Comment: Not necessarily. I used an if statement preventing everything when clicked on active element.